# Unity ARfundation for android 7.1

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to develop an augmented reality project but I want to cover from android 7.1, working with unity 2019.4.28 and ArFundation 2.1.18 and when I try it on my android device it tells me that it requires the newest version of "google play services for ra" and sends me to play store and tells me that my device is not compatible, what can I?

I have tried previous versions of unity and arfundation but none of them work for me.